# Mono Develop not Compliling GUI Changes

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I am having a problem with MonoDevelop. When I attempt to debug/run my program after making changes to interface icons/text etc. Nothing happens. However, the code itself seems to be compiled properly, for example if I change `about.Version` from `about.Version = "1.0";` to `about.Version = "1.0 (RC)";` the change is reflected after compiling.

On the other hand, if I change the default text in a textview, or icons on a toolbar, they won't change.

I tried deleting the .exe file, but it still compiled with the GUI.

In addition, and this could be related, I removed `this.applyAction.Activated += new global::System.EventHandler (this.OnApplyActionActivated);` from the gtk file, and now, each and every time I compile, I have to select either 'keep changes' or 'reload from disk.' The program can't seem to just get over it and remember my choice... it keeps trying to add `this.applyAction.Activated += new global::System.EventHandler (this.OnApplyActionActivated);` back in and ask me each time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you Do "Build" -> "Clean All" first or alternatively "Build" -> "Rebuild All"

Comment: Oh, and check in Options -> Preferences -> Build to see if you might be using the Experimental integration with XBuild

Comment: @miracledev That doesn't fix it. I have a solution now posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding the signal's receiving method back into the C# file, and then clicking "Reload from Disk" within the corresponding GTK file. Finally, I saved and ran the program, and was delighted to find the problem fixed.

The method is empty, except for throwing a `System.NotImpletentedException` when called, but that's no issue because there are no interface objects that call the method.